# How to array merge two multi-dimensional arrays without them overwriting each other?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, formatting, array-merge

I have two multi dimensional arrays which have similar keys. If i use array_merge on them, the values get overwritten since they have similar keys. My goal is to append a lot of such arrays with similar keys into a single array.
Example :

```
***array 1:*** =
array (
  'Shopping and fashion' => 
  array (
    'Beauty' => 
    array (
      'Cosmetics' => 
      array (
        'Cosmetics' => 
        array (
          0 => '6002839660079',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)

***array 2:*** =
array (
  'Shopping and fashion' => 
  array (
    'Beauty' => 
    array (
      'Beauty' => 
      array (
        0 => '6002867432822',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I would like to combine them as follows:

```
array (
  'Shopping and fashion' => 
  array (
    'Beauty' => 
    array (
      'Cosmetics' => 
      array (
        'Cosmetics' => 
        array (
          0 => 'Cosmetics-6002839660079',
        ),
      ),
      'Beauty' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Beauty-6002867432822',
      ),
    ),
  )
)
```

It is important I maintain the structure of the arrays as it is.
I can provide more examples if needed

Comment: `array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2)`

Comment: thank you so much my man. I have been wrecking my brains over this for a while now.
I looped over all arrays i have used this 
    $final = array_merge_recursive($final,$arr);